# Could not initialize bean class in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

I am trying to develop rest code using spring.

```
@RestController
public class MongoController {

    @Autowired
    private MongoDAO mongoDAO ;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/mongotest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String creatTest() {

        return " YO Mongo";
    }


}
```

And my MongoDAO class looks like below

```
@Service("mongoDAO")
@Component
public class MongoDAO {


    @Resource
    private DBCollection user ;
    @Resource
    private MongoDatabase userDatabase;
    @Resource
    private MongoCollection<Document> usersCollection;
    @Resource
    private MongoClient mongoClient;

/*  public MongoDAO(final MongoDatabase userDatabase) {
        usersCollection = userDatabase.getCollection("user");
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("ITAU");
        user = db.getCollection("user");
    }*/

    public MongoDAO(MongoDatabase userDatabase1) {
        usersCollection = userDatabase1.getCollection("user");

    }

    public MongoDAO() {
        usersCollection = userDatabase.getCollection("user");

    }
```

But the error I am getting  is ..

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'mongoDAO' defined in file
>   [C:\Users\user\Desktop\ITAU\77\ABC-iCOE-WAL\ItauBankingTransac
>   s\rest-client\target\classes\com\ABC\WAL\itaudemo\mongo\dao\MongoDAO.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could n
>   nstantiate bean class [com.ABC.WAL.itaudemo.mongo.dao.MongoDAO]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field `userDatabase` is autowired after creating `MongoDao` bean. If you want to perform some after constructing actions try this:

```
@Service("mongoDAO")
public class MongoDAO {


    @Resource
    private DBCollection user ;
    @Resource
    private MongoDatabase userDatabase;
    @Resource
    private MongoCollection<Document> usersCollection;
    @Resource
    private MongoClient mongoClient;

    public MongoDAO() {

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public postConstruct() {
        usersCollection = userDatabase.getCollection("user");

    }
```

The constructor might be omitted. Generally it is better not to have custom constructors for component classes.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `@Service("mongoDAO")` no need of `@Component`

```
@Service("mongoDAO")
public class MongoDAO {
```

You can use either of the two annotations, @Service is used in service layer code for readability. @Component is more of a generic annotation.

Comment: Of course what you say is right but It doesn't address @Aman issue.